# Failed to parse field, elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

Classic elasticsearch not parsing your date. Maybe i'm starting to go blind. I don't know what i'm doing wrong, my template:

```
"datestamp": {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  "type": "date",                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

The response:

```
'failed to parse field [datestamp] of type [date]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Invalid format: "2019-05-08 04:00:00" is malformed at "19-05-08 04:00:00"'
```

From a date string: `2019-05-08 04:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete my previous index.